# Why does Heroku's bundler update the gems everytime I push?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler

I'm running multiple of my Rails apps on Heroku. I use most of the standards including Gemfile and Bundler. Gemfile.lock is commited with Git.

However, when I push to Heroku, instead of reading Gemfile.lock, it seems to just run `bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/` from afresh, which means it updates the gems every time I push, causing discrepancies between my dev and prod environments.

I get no error message, but that's not the behavior I expect. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: you should write the gem version you expect in your gemfile

Comment: I so wish heroku could reduce their push times.

Comment: bundle install uses the versions as specified in Gemfile.lock and Gemfile it doesn't update gems unless something has changed. e.g. Gemfile specifies a new gem or a different version of a gem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it does this s part of it's 'build everything from the ground up in case the developers system has any differences" philosophy.
For example if you were running "ibuntu" (made up) and your environment had different dependencies between gems due to the way ruby is implemented on your system.  Its safer just to build everything from scratch o their system and make sure that any dependencies that come up in their stack get met.

Comment: Well, that kind of sucks... I got into troubles a few times because the new gem it was updating to was buggy or just completely refactored with new configurations.

Comment: Bundler allows you to freeze the version of a gem that you are using. Check out the Bundler syntax at http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html.

The idea is that you would specify versions with something like
    `gem "rack",  ">=1.0"` or
    `gem "thin",  "~>1.1"`

Comment: Yes, I find it a bit overkill though... Guess there's no other choice.